# Group by months using PERIOD_DIFF mysql

Tags: mysql, period

I have the following table name surveydb,I use mysql 5.7

| PERIODE | SURVEY |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-02-03 | 2 |
| 2020-02-04 | 3 |
| 2020-03-10 | 5 |
| 2020-03-11 | 4 |
| 2020-07-28 | 1 |
| 2020-08-28 | 3 |
| 2020-11-28 | 4 |

I Used the following query in mysql,

```
SELECT `SURVEY`,MIN(`PERIODE`) AS `Range Start`, MAX(`PERIODE`) AS `Range End`, COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM `surveydb`
GROUP BY FLOOR(PERIOD_DIFF(@T1, DATE_FORMAT(`PERIODE`, '%Y%m')) / 3)
```

I want to group by 3 months interval but the result is different,

only 1 survey is shown for date interval from 2020-02-03 to 2020-03-11 although they have different survey values, how do I show all surveys for the range of each group

| SURVEY | RANGE START | RANGE END | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-02-03 | 2020-03-11 | 4 |
| 1 | 2020-07-28 | 2020-08-28 | 2 |

I can not show all surveys within the months interval, for example from 2020-02-03 to 2020-03-11

Instead, I want to get results like this:

| SURVEY | RANGE START | RANGE END | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-02-03 | 2020-03-11 | 4 |
| 3 | 2020-02-03 | 2020-02-03 | 4 |
| 5 | 2020-02-03 | 2020-02-03 | 4 |
| 4 | 2020-02-03 | 2020-02-03 | 4 |
| 1 | 2020-07-28 | 2020-08-28 | 2 |

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - and clarify which version of MySQL you're using

Answer (score 0):

seems you need  group by  SURVEY too

```
SELECT `SURVEY`,MIN(`PERIODE`) AS `Range Start`, MAX(`PERIODE`) AS `Range End`, COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM `surveydb`
GROUP BY `SURVEY`, FLOOR(PERIOD_DIFF(@T1, DATE_FORMAT(`PERIODE`, '%Y%m')) / 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a window functions rather than aggregation?

```
select survey,
    min(periode) over(partition by floor(period_diff(@t1, date_format(periode, '%y%m')) / 3)) as range_start, 
    min(periode) over(partition by floor(period_diff(@t1, date_format(periode, '%y%m')) / 3)) as range_end, 
    count(*)     over(partition by floor(period_diff(@t1, date_format(periode, '%y%m')) / 3)) as cnt
from surveydb
```

We could shorten the query with a named window:

```
select survey,
    min(periode) over w as range_start, 
    min(periode) over w as range_end, 
    count(*)     over w as cnt
from surveydb
window w as (partition by floor(period_diff(@t1, date_format(periode, '%y%m')) / 3))
```